# How to compile Java files silently unless there are errors?

Tags: java, batch-file, jar

I have following commands in a shell.cmd file, and it runs correctly.

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\javac.exe" -verbose -g -cp "SOMETHING" -d "../classes" *.java

cd ..

if not exist dist mkdir dist

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\jar.exe" cf "./dist/my.jar" -C ./classes .
```

But, I get a lot of output to the console during compilation to `.class` and then when creating `.jar` files.

How can I disable the messages? Without disabling error messages.

Comment: remove the `-verbose` flag from the javac command

Comment: If you don't want verbose output why are you specifying it?

Comment: @EJP I copied the script from somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `@echo off`, and remove the `-verbose` flag. And, I'd add the Java `bin` folder to the path. Something like,

```
@echo off
set "JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51"
set "PATH=%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin"
javac.exe -g -cp "SOMETHING" -d "../classes" *.java

cd ..

if not exist dist mkdir dist

jar.exe cf "./dist/my.jar" -C ./classes .
```

Comment: I could understand remove -verbose will remove messages for javac.exe; however, why it affect jar.exe?

Comment: How did you know I want @echo off as well, even though I didn't ask. Magic you! Thanks

Comment: @milesma It doesn't. But you have `echo on`, and a verbose `jar` is `jar cfv`.

Comment: @milesma it is common almost all batch scripts, with echo off.